# Converting a object into a generic class without knowing Type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have that interface :

```
public interface IEntityWithTypedId<T>{
     T Id { get; }
}
```

And have two classes :

```
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId> : IEntityWithTypedId<TId>{...}
public abstract class Entity : EntityWithTypedId<int>{...}
```

So, I have entities like these:

```
public class TestA : Entity
public class TestB : EntityWithTypedId<string>
public class TestC : EntityWithTypedId<byte>
```

Now I have an **object** and need to cast it to `IEntityWithTypedId<T>`
I can do that with nested *ifs*, checking the **object** type. But I am looking for a generic solution.

I need to get the **Id** value (as a string, so I dont care what is the T)

Example :

```
var idString = ((IEntityWithTypedId<long>)object).Id.ToString();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't know `T` even as a generic type parameter, how would you expect to use it? Perhaps you should have a non-generic interface that you could cast to instead (or as well)...

Comment: My IEntityWithTypedId has a property Id and I need to get that value as a string (so I dont care about T). Something like that : var id = ((IEntityWithTypedId<int>)object).Id.ToString()

Comment: Right, so you should have a non-generic interface, as I suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another interface

```
public interface IEntityStringId
{
     String IDString { get; }
}

public interface IEntityWithTypedId<T> : IEntityStringId
{

}
```

Then cast to that interface:

```
var idstring = ((IEntityStringId)obj).IDString;
```

Comment: I need to access the Id property.

Comment: which you will do from your implementation of IDString